# Bypass install configuration in dockerfile

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt-get, icinga

I am trying to install icinga2-ido-pgsql on an Ubuntu Docker container.
My database is in a separate container.
To install it I run

```
RUN apt-get install -q -y icinga2 icinga2-ido-pgsql
```

When installing icinga2-ido-pgsql it runs dbconfig-common which gives the prompt.

```
Configure database for icinga2-ido-pgsql with dbconfig-common? [yes/no]
```

Which then gives me a load of errors because it is defaulting to yes and I am not running an interactive terminal.

I want to say no, and do things manually but I don't know how to get this behaviour through my dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following to tell whether apt packages should be prompting you or not:

`DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`

So doing a `RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -q -y icinga2 icinga2-ido-pgsql` should be running fine then.